# how to convert line breaks stored in mySQL to a single line

Tags: php, tags, meta

I have descriptions stored in mySQL with line breaks, so when I output them as they should be, I use:

```
<?
echo nl2br($description);
?>
```

And it shows:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

So far, so good. Now, I want to use that same description for the meta tags and the problem is that even if I output them like:

```
$old_string = nl2br($description);
$new_string = preg_replace("/<br \/>/"," ",$old_string);
echo $new_string;
```

I still get these meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Line 1

Line 2

Line 3"/>
```

How do I make it output all in 1 line, with just a space in between them?

Thank you very much for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `nl2br` for META, but simply replace line-breaks on the string from database. Note that depending on your environment, a linebreak can be represented with `\r\n` or simply with `\n`. So try to use the following code:

```
$onelinestring = str_replace("\r\n", " ", $description);
$onelinestring = str_replace("\n", " ", $onelinestring);
```

Comment: Redundant code, just provide array for str_replace, instead of calling it twice: str_replace(array(PHP_EOL, "\r\n"), " ", $string);

Comment: @MichaelArenzon yes, possibly a bit redundant, BUT it expresses that the order of the replaces is very important, and one should not rely on underlying framework implementations to ensure it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$singleLine = str_replace("\n", " ", $string);
```

Without nl2br, just the string fetched from the db.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yours was faster but the one below with the \r\n actually fixed my issue. Thank you anyways :)